# Contact Information Issue

Tags: contact-us

I'm working with a client that is excited about their untested "contact bar" that reads visitors IP address and displays a person's contact info (image, name email, phone) permanently fixed at the bottom of the page.

This may or may not be the best person to solve their problems. If it is not the best person there are links to help them find the best person.

My question: Is it better to show a contact person that is inaccurate or none at all? Since it wasn't tested we don't know if users can get to the "right" person or if they act on the first viable option.

There is also a traditional Contact Us link in the global navigation.

Comment: Which conditions can define an accurate from an inaccurate person? I see that location is a top one since IP is the main way to differentiate persons to suggest.

Comment: How does the user know the contact person is or is not the right one? Should it be their responsibility to contact the right person? Or should it be your client's responsibility to do that?

Answer (score 3):

**Promote the traditional/non-specific contact method in the UI**

The real estate marketplace website www.zillow.com has a relevant design pattern that might be worth considering here.

When viewing a listing, the site shows some recommended agents based on the location, but the primary interaction for that part of the UI is a regular contact form.

This might be trickier for you to implement given that you're working in a bar, but the concept is still applicable.

[image]

Comment: Answer should have been accepted and upvoted more. This is without a doubt the perfect solution for the problem mentioned above. It gives the users freedom to pick their own agent, or have someone assigned to them.